# How does a piston push on an enclosed, in-compressible liquid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

[image]

If I exerted a force $ F_1 $ onto an enclosed, in-compressible fluid then Pascal states that the change in the pressure that the fluid exerts on the container is distributed evenly at all points in the fluid.

According to my understanding, the piston that I use to exert $ F_1 $ never moves because the fluid exerts an equal pressure on the piston. So the piston on the other side would never move because no fluid is displaced? There is clearly a hole in my understanding of Pascal's law.

Comment: Incompressible is not the same as ‘can’t move’.

Comment: In-compressible means that the pressure exerted on the fluid does not cause a change in the density of the fluid.

Comment: Re, "There is clearly a hole in my understanding of Pascal's law." I think it goes beyond Pascal's Law because according to that same logic, you could also say that if a box sits on a slippery floor, and you push on it, the box will never move because the box exerts a force on your hand that is equal and opposite to the force that your hand exerts on the box.

Comment: @Solomon Slow No, I disagree. In your example, the box would move because the forces may be equal and opposite, but they are acting on different bodies and therefore do not cancel out. In my case, I exert a force on piston 1, the fluid exerts an equal and opposite force that also acts on the piston. It's as if two people are pushing on a door with equal force.

Comment: OK, So, two boxes (corresponding to two pistons) connected by a rigid rod (corresponding to the incompressible fluid). According to my understanding, the box that I use to exert $F_1$ never moves because the rod exerts an equal force on the box. So, the box on the other end would never move because the rod never moves. Sounds like an isomorphic argument to me.

Answer (score 0):

If both pistons are free, a strong enough pressure on piston 1 will create a movement that will move both pistons, lowering one and lifting the other.
If piston 2 is fixed, a force on piston 1 will increase the fluid pressure, but it will not move.
The fact the the fluid exerts a pressure on the piston does not means it cannot move. The same thing happens when you push into an object, it will exert an opposite force into your hand, but it will move if the object is free, and you will not if you are anchored by friction into the ground.

Comment: Does the fluid exert a pressure on piston 1, that is equal to the pressure that it exerts on the fluid? Because, if so, the two forces acting on the piston must cancel and therefore it can't accelerate. In your example, the two opposite forces are acting on separate bodies so that's why the object moves.